# Why I cannot export tabSelectedTextColor to xml style?

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I am using Material `TabLayout`. I have lots of tabs that use the same style that is why I decided to move the styling to `TabStyle` style like this:

```
 <style name="TabStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@color/gray_b0</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/black</item>  <!--THIS IS NOT RECOGNIZED -->
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Font.OpenSans.Semibold.Small.Capital</item>
 </style>
```

The problem is attribute `tabSelectedTextColor` is not recognized. What might be the problem here? Why are other attributes working fine?

Comment: Can you add detail error message?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman It is very wierd after I rebuild the project it is now working.